# (Java) Change swing components' text at runtime (resource bundles)

Tags: java, swing, runtime, refresh

I'm setting the value of a JLabel with

```
myLabel.setText( controller.getString("hello") );
```

where controller.getString returns the getString from a ResourceBundle instance.

However, I'm trying to update the language of the application at runtime and I'm having the hardest time to figure out how to 'refresh' the label's text so that it users the new Locale's getString.

I use an observer-pattern that updates my frame whenever the language is switched.

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

John Neumann.

Answer (score 1):

If you call setText again, the label will be updated.  So in your implementation of the Observer interface, when the language switches you can ensure all your labels are the right language by calling that same setText method.